# About WAP websites

Tags: wap

How to create a WAP website? 
What software do I use?
Do I just need to use HTML coding or other type of language?
And after I created it, Can I view it on my own phone?
Do I need a server to let it run or I can just view it on my phone?

Can someone help please, its for my project.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

What phones are you targeting? Any phone released in the last 3-5 years is able to view standard (X)HTML without issue - except for the fact that they mostly have very small screens.

Some phones do not support Javascript very well (but that is mostly changing, too) and most phones do not support Flash (yet - most newish phones except iPhone will probably support flash "soon", if not already).

The only other main difference is that most phones these days use a touch interface, rather than a traditional keyboard/mouse. That means you can't really do things like hover effects and so on.

But other than the smaller size, everything else is pretty minor.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the post above that unless you are targeting very old phones, there is probably very little point to working with WAP today - AFAIK the last official version was WAP 2.0 which was circa 2002.

WAP 2.0 used a streamlined version of XHTML. The best way to develop is to either navigate your phone to a standard HTTP server hosting your files - or download and use a simulator. I found the best practice was to develop the app until it worked on the simulator (which could often be directed to load local files) and then do final testing and tweaking with actual devices.